# What does it mean when "The troll pounced"?

Tags: phrases

What does it mean when "The troll pounced"?

That is something I saw on a SAT workbook.

Comment: What does your dictionary tell you about the English noun _troll_ and the verb _to pounce?_ Please use the [edit] link to tell us what you do not understand about those definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a [**troll**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/troll#References_2)

is a *mythical being* of various size who is usually *anti-social* and lives in a wood, a cave, or under a bridge and can be very *territorial*.

[image]

> to **pounce**

is to jump on something, usually some sort of *prey* to *capture* it, cats are often described as "**pouncing**"

[image]
[image]

In your case, it might be something similar to this troll wearing a blue helmet

[image]

Comment: You know, for all the clear explanations I try to give verbally, I have to admit that something about pictures makes them seem like great tools for language learning. Vivid, immediate, and likelier to bring the word in the learner's native language to their mind...

Comment: @LukeSawczak  "*A picture is worth a thousand words*"... images transcend language.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that while some trolls are smaller than humans, others are considerably larger.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Quite! In the origin myths, there is nothing cuddly or winsomely mischievous about the _troll._ None of these graphics speak even remotely to the actual nature of the archetypal troll. What is that last thing? Some kind of cross-cultural manga demon?

Comment: @P.E.Dant: The one caught underneath is a Homestuck troll. I'm not so sure about the other one. Might be another such troll wearing cat ears and tail. Because of course.

Comment: @P.E.Dant  [Nepeta Nintendo pouncing](http://nintendo-nut1.deviantart.com/art/Nepeta-Pounce-on-Karkitty-256285711)

Comment: @P.E.Dant it's an alien species from a webcomic. They got called trolls because the author wanted humans in the webcomic to initially mistake them for internet trolls. The different culture and biology made these trolls say things worthy of an internet troll without realizing, making it harder for them to be taken seriously, which is an hilarious plot point of the saga. This fanart is drawn in manga style but the webcomic isn't (except for some parts where the style intentionally changes, and not exclusively to manga).